# How to remove the duplicated values from the Excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm trying to read the values of the columns in an excel sheet, and I want to skip the duplicated row by comparing it to the previous values of the column, and then I want to write the values in two list one is to store Names other one to store continental.

ex: Row 5 must be skipped because it is repeated in row 1

L1 = [a,b,c,b,c]
L2 = [Asia,Asia,Asia,Europe,Europe]

[image]

Kindly assist me
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your problem is?

Comment: what's your current code and what are you planning on doing?

i'm not sure how right am i about this, but i think you're trying to make sure nothing gets repeated. in that case, you can simply make something like a dictionary
```dict(EXEL_DATA)```
dict() takes in a list, and makes it into a key-value data type called dictionary.
remember though, this only works if you have 1 key and 1 value.


if this isn't what you meant, then feel free to explain what did you mean

Comment: Use tuples in a set.

Answer (score 2):

Code update to output as lists
Create a single nested list 'NL' with row data combined in a list of lists and then split the list into two separate lists per the comment.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fname = 'foo.xlsx'
value_list = list()
wb = load_workbook(fname)
ws = wb.active

NL = []
L1 = []
L2 = []

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    name = row[0].value
    continent = row[1].value
    if [name, continent] not in NL:
        NL.append([name, continent])

print(f'Nested List: {NL}')

for slist in NL:
    L1.append(slist[0])
    L2.append(slist[1])


print(f'L1: {L1}\nL2: {L2}')
```

Output Lists;
Nested list with column values combined and the two separated list,
L1 from column 'Names'
L2 from column 'continental'

```
Nested List: [['a', 'Asia'], ['b', 'Asia'], ['c', 'Asia'], ['b', 'Europe'], ['c', 'Europe']]
L1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
L2: ['Asia', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Europe']
```

Comment: thank you for the response its really help full, but one more request instead of dictionary is it possible to use list, ex: 
L1 = [a,b,c,b,c]
L2 = [Asia,Asia,Asia,Europe,Europe]

Answer (score 0):

```
value_list = list()
wb = load_workbook(fname)
ws = wb.active
for myrow in range(1, ws.max_row):
    for mycol in range(1, ws.max_column):
        cell_val = ws.cell(row=myrow, column=mycol).value
        if(cell_val not in value_list):
            value_list.append(cell_val)
print(value_list)
```

This code should work in openpyxl to first searching through every single row and column in your spreadsheet, then adding the cell value into the list if it does not already exist.

Alternately, if you already have a list and your list has duplicated values that you'd like to remove, you can convert your list to a set and then convert it back into a list like so:

```
dup_list = list(set(dup_list))
```

More info below:
https://java2blog.com/python-list-to-set/#google_vignette

Comment: This code sample would just produce a list with the values `['Name', 'a', 'b', 'c']` from the first 4 rows. It doesn't skip the header and misses the last row. `for mycol in range(1, ws.max_column):` would appear to be redundant since `ws.max_column` would have a value of 2 though presume like the row iteration this is meant to include the last column but does not.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i want to check the values in both name and continental column and if name and continental column value repeated previously i need to skip that combination